# IIS - How to edit local config for application with Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I can create a website using ServerManager just fine using:

```
iisApplication = site.Applications.Add("/MySite", SomePath);
```

I want to edit some properties (but only specific to this application, not site or server-wide). Using this code

```
            Configuration config = iisApplication.GetWebConfiguration();

            ConfigurationSection defaultDocumentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/defaultDocument");
            ConfigurationElementCollection documents = defaultDocumentSection.GetCollection("files");
            documents.Clear();
            ConfigurationElement document = documents.CreateElement();
            document["value"] = "MyFile.aspx"; 
            documents.Add(document);
```

As soon as I commit changes I get the error

```
Filename: \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\web.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file
```

Now it looks as though GetWebConfiguration() is pulling in the wrong web.config file because my site is not stored in inetpub, it is in a different folder.

How do I edit web.config in the local website folder?   This is winforms.

Comment: You'd better edit your question as your code creates an application under a site, not a new site.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - it has to be edited at a higher level using the 'location' path:

```
config = iisManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", "Default Web Site/MySite);
anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true;
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this link

[Creating a new website programmatically on IIS using ASP.NET and C#](https://stweet.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/creating-a-new-website-programmatically-on-iis-using-asp-net/)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try that solution because it appears to use different technology to mine